# Handling millions of rows in Python

Tags: python, csv, bigdata, time-complexity

I would like preface this question with the fact that I have done my research on python time complexity and data structures that are available to speed things up.

However, I am struggling to think of an efficient way to check a set of values against a 2.5 million row file. One solution I have considered thus far has been the use of list comprehensions.

Currently, I am trying to handle that in the following manner:

```
def getTotalVolumeByCounty(fileName, counties):

values = []

with open(fileName) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)

    headers = next(csvReader)

    for row in csvReader:

        i = 0
        while i < len(counties):
            if row[9] == counties[i]:
                values[i] += int(row[22])
                break
return values
```

The "traditional" manner if you will. Comparing each value from one list against the current value in the other list. Obviously this is not favorable in terms of time complexity.

As previously stated, I have thought about using list comprehensions - but how do these actually save time? Is a list comprehension my only alternative to the current attempt?

Comment: Can you confirm that the data in the 2.5 million row file will be sorted?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop?  `i` never changes, nor does `len(counties)`, so the loop never executes.

Comment: I can confirm that. There are 2.5 million rows, and I need to sort through them. I have to go through and add up the total volume sold per county.

Comment: Also, `values` is initialized to an empty list and no elements are ever added.  So if the line `values[i] += int(row[22])` ever did execute, it would be an error, as `values[i]` does not exist.

Comment: By sorted I meant ordered by some key, for example, ordered by some value that identifies a county. This would look like all records for a specific county being grouped together within the data.

Comment: As far as I am aware, list comprehensions aren't any faster than a traditional loop.  Their purpose is to allow _nicer-looking_ code, not _faster_ code.

Comment: Guys, ignore the while loop for now. The point is simply to represent the idea of doing it the 'traditional' way. I am looking for a faster way

Comment: what are you supposed to do with these rows ? Isn't clear from code (don't see i incrementing, values[i] will fail) et

Comment: If a match is found, I want to add the sale by volume column to the running total.

Comment: List comprehensions are just ways to write a normal for-loop that appends to a list. This doesn't help you here. You want to keep the values you will be repeatedly checking in a *`set`*  object for efficient lookups. Presumably in this case it is `countries`. And listen, don't post code and say "ignore it". *You don't post irrelevant code*. You need to tell us precisely what it is you are trying to accomplish. That is how you can get the best help around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.5 million rows is not a lot these days but your not quite working code is multiplying each line check by the number of counties in terms of the work and that will make it very slow. If we use an intermediate dictionary of your counties we can do it much faster like this:

```
def get_total_volume_by_county(file_name, counties):
    county_volume_map = {county: 0 for county in counties}

    with open(file_name) as csv:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv)

        headers = next(csv_reader)

        for row in csv_reader:
            county_volume_map[row[9]] += row[22]

    return county_volume_map
```

If you really just want the list of volumes, you can convert it back at the end but a map of county to volume is probably more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment thread on the OP, I'll add a suggestion here.

When working with large amounts of data, it's usually more efficient to first sort the data in some way and then use something like binary search to find blocks of data.

For example, you mention that you want to compare items in one list to items in a second list. For the purposes of this I will assume the size of the first list (list A) is small and the second (list B) large.

If the items in list B are ordered by some key, for example, the County name (assuming all Counties have a unique name) you could use a [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find a random (essentially) item within the block of entries for the County and then depending on the number of entries for any given County, you would either do 2 loops to find the upper and lower bound or another Binary Search or similar on a different key by which the list would be ordered second to the original key (such as total volume) which would leave you with a list of just the items that match some metric determined by you.

If the data is not sorted already, it would probably be worth sorting it as the time complexity of Heapsort or Quicksort is at worst O(nlogn) and binary search is at worst O(logn). The time complexity of looping over your lists would probably be on the order of O(kn^k) or something, which if you were to graph, would be many times worse.

As to the last part of your question, list comprehension is just syntactic sugar and doesn't do anything particularly fancy.

tldr; sort the data by some unique identifier, I recommend using [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) as it's in-place, generic in that you can provide a comparison function and it will work with that, and you could probably look up an iterative implementation in Python. Then using Binary search to find items efficiently.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really, in Python, you would generally just put your items in a `set`. In this case, iterating a 2million line file and checking for matches of `countries` where `countries` is a `set` object would be very fast and the code very minimal.

Comment: You could do, I just assumed the data would be some arbitrary string like "CountyName,Volume,Amount,Date,ProductId,...,..." or similar and that it might be faster to sort manually than to try and rely on the Python interpreter to do that kind of thing if you're after speed.

Comment: Huh? Yes, clearly they are using a csv. I don't think it is *ever* faster to sort manually in Python. I'm highly skeptical you would beat Timsort implemented in C. If you sort manually, *you are relying on the python interpreter*.

Comment: If you can supply your own comparison function to the default sort method then I completely agree. My point about using sorted data to improve speed isn't dependent on the specific method of sorting, just that the data is sorted before searching.

Answer (score 0):

Going totally based off of the name of your function and it's signature, I'm going to assume you are merely trying to group the total volume of sales by country, where `countries` is a list of the countries you are interested in. The most straight-forward way in Python is to use a `dict` of counts. Grouping is idiomatically done with `dict` objects. In this case, your `dict` will serve as "set" as well, because we will initialize the dict with `0` for every country. Then just check if the country is in the dict before augmenting the corresponding value.

```
def get_total_volume_by_country(file_name, counties):
    volume_by_country = dict.fromkeys(countries, 0)
    with open(file_name) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        headers = next(csv_reader)

        for row in csv_reader:
            country = row[9] # presumably country name
            if country in volume_by_country:
                volume_by_country[country] += int(row[22]) # volume presumably
    return volume_by_country
```

Comment: Almost snap with my answer (sorry - we overlapped ;) but you are adding each county volume to all county volumes I think (county might equal country ;)).

Comment: @PaulWhipp I don't think so, `volume_by_country[country] += int(row[22])` but I haven't actually tested this code. Maybe we interpreted the question differently?

Comment: @PaulWhipp ah, perhaps you missed this line in mine: `volume_by_country = dict.fromkeys(countries, 0)`. Ours are essentially equivalent, but yours assumes every country encountered actually exists in `countries`. I'm assuming that may not be the case.

Comment: @jaunpa.arrivillaga: You are right, sorry. I skimmed your conditional as being the original for loop.